# jQuery memory leak with repeated .ajax calls

Tags: jquery, firefox, memory-leaks

I'm using the following pattern which is leaking memory in Firefox:

```
$(function() {

    (function() {

        var callee = arguments.callee;

        $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            success: function() { ... setTimeout(callee, 1000); },
            error: function() { ... setTimeout(callee, 1000); }
        });

    })();

});
```

The memory leak remains, even when success/error do nothing other than calling setTimeout again. I'm observing the leak via Windows Task Manager; if the page is left open, memory usage of firefox.exe slowly creeps up. For the final version of this code, I only need to update once a minute, but once-a-second demonstrates the memory leak much faster!

*(Note: this looks like a very similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455947/memory-leak-involving-jquery-ajax-requests), but the selected answer there doesn't appear to cater for Firefox)*

Comment: what is the function callee doing? are you sure there are no circular references,.?

Comment: The 'callee' pattern is just a way of timing code within an anonymous function. Even with the code literally as bare as it is above, there's still a memory leak.

Comment: The pattern is discussed in Paul Irish's excellent [Things I learned from the jquery source](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) video - see around the 8 minute mark

Comment: I have had the same problem try using a queue.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce the problem and solved it as such:

```
$(function() 
{
    function checkStatus() 
    {
        $.ajax({
          url: '...',
          success: function() { ... setTimeout(checkStatus, 1000); },
          error: function() { ... setTimeout(checkStatus, 1000); }
        });

    }

    checkStatus();

});
```

What appears to happen is each time your anonymous method is called, it creates a variable and assigns a reference to it.  Given enough time, this will fill up memory.

This solution just passes the same function ref around rather than creating a new one with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

maybe worth trying something like this?

```
$(function() 
{
    (function() 
    {
        var callee = arguments.callee;
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '...',
            success: function() 
            {
                ... 
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    callee();
                }, 1000);
             },
             error: function() 
             {
                ... 
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    callee();
                }, 1000);
              }
        });   
    })();
});
```

so instad of passing calle to the setTimeout callback, pass an anonymous function that calls calle.

Answer (score -3):

Try putting callee outside of the functions like so:

```
var callee = arguments.callee;

$(function() {

    (function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            success: function() { ... setTimeout(callee, 1000); },
            error: function() { ... setTimeout(callee, 1000); }
        });

    })();

});
```

So that memory gets allocated only once for "callee", and not everytime the functions are executed.

Comment: `callee` *must* be inside the function, since it refers to the function itself