# IE memory leak and eval with jQuery

Tags: memory, jquery, memory-leaks

I've created a page which needs to have its elements updated according what's happening with the data in our database. I'd like to know what do you think about this approach using eval, I know it's risky but in my case it was the fastest way.

```
$('.updatable').each(function () {
        var data;
        data = 'ViewObjectId=' + $(this).attr('objectid');

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: '/Ajax/GetUpdatedViewObjectDataHandler.ashx',
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        eval(value);
                });
            }
        });
```

*Now the issue I have is when the page is loaded, for each 10 seconds the page is updated, until here it's perfect.*

*After each round of updates, my Internet Explorer steal some memory, and it gets the whole machine memory after some hours, terrific.*

**What would you do in this case? Some other update approach is recommended? Or even, is there something you think I could do to avoid this memory leak?**

Comment: I've removed the eval function and created a new function, but the leak still there.

Comment: The problem is in the ajax call: $.ajax( -> I don't know why yet.

Comment: According this post, the anonimous calls was generating the memory leaking... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617442/jquery-memory-leak-with-repeated-ajax-calls 

I'm testing and seems to be getting better.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429056/simple-jquery-ajax-call-leaks-memory-in-internet-explorer

Comment: THE SOLUTION:
 var request = $.ajax({ .... });
 
 request.onreadystatechange = null; 
 request.abort = null; 
 request = null;

JQuery doesn't do that and the memory never releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Simple jQuery Ajax call leaks memory in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429056/simple-jquery-ajax-call-leaks-memory-in-internet-explorer)

**THE SOLUTION:**

```
 var request = $.ajax({ .... });

 request.onreadystatechange = null; 
 request.abort = null; 
 request = null;
```

JQuery doesn't do that and the memory never releases.

jQuery version 1.4.2.

*Now it's working like a charm.*

Comment: Any chance you've found one that does?